# if u,v are nonzero, show that $w = \|v\| u + \|u\| v$ bisects the angle between u and v

Tags: vectors

(self study) My work, given w = $\|v\| u + \|u\| v$

$u.w = u.(\| v\| u + \|u \|v)
    = \|v\| (u.u) + \|u \| (u.v)
$

$v.w = v.(\|v\|u + \|u\|v)
    = \|v\| (v.u) + \|u\| (v.v)
$

Let $\alpha$ be the angle between u,w and
    $\beta$ be the angle between v,w

$\cos \alpha = \frac{u.w}{\|u\| \|w\|} $,
$\cos \beta = \frac{v.w}{\|v\| \|w\|}$

$\cos \alpha= \frac{\|v\| (u.u) + \|u\| (u.v)}{\|u\|\|w\|} = \frac{\|v\|\|u\| + (v.u)}{\|w\|}$

$\cos \beta = \frac{\|v\|(v.u) + \|u\| (v.v)}{\|v\| \|w\|} = \frac{(v.u) + \|u\|\|v\|}{\|w\|}$

since $\cos \alpha = \cos\beta $.
w bisects the angle between u,v. Is my proof correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is another way to see this. pick the points $A=\frac{u}{\|u \|}, B = \frac{v}{\| v \|}$ that are unit distance from the origin making $OAB$  an isoscles triangle. the midpoint $\frac12\left(\frac{u}{\|u \|}+\frac{v}{\| v \|}\right)$ is on the bisector of $u$ and $v.$ multiply by the scalar $2\|u\| \|v\|$ to arrive at your result.

Comment: Thanks for the alternate insight, can i know why we need to multiply by $2\|u\|\|v\|$

Comment: @NagaChaitanyaVellanki, any scalar multiple of a vector stays on the same line, in our case, on the bisector of $u$ and $v.$

Answer (score 0):

It is very neat, but you have to be careful about the denominator.

w must be non-zero, which means -∥v∥u = ∥u∥v, -u/∥u∥=v/∥v∥, the condition is raised to when u != -kv for any k>0